# VectorTileServer works using web links but not using ArcMap--Add ArcGIS server

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, vector-tiles

In ArcMap I am trying to add the following ArcGIS server

https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/Mobile_3G_ExtAntenna/VectorTileServer

It connects fine but I don't see anything in the hosted folder
[image]

If I use a link from the page above I can see the service in a web map
https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/Mobile_3G_ExtAntenna/VectorTileServer?f=jsapi
[image]

Is there any way to see this in ArcMap (10.8)

Comment: I don't *think* ArcGIS Desktop supports vector tile services

Comment: ArcMap does not support MVT PBF vector tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried [searching for "vector tiles" in the ArcMap 10.8 help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/search/?q=%22vector%20tiles%22&collection=help&product=arcgis-desktop&version=10.8&language=en) and it found 0 results.

I then tried [searching for "vector tiles" in the ArcGIS Pro 2.7 help](https://pro.arcgis.com/search/?q=%22vector%20tiles%22&collection=help&product=arcgis-desktop&language=en) and it found 87 results.

It appears that the functionality you seek, while found in the ArcGIS Desktop product, is only found in its ArcGIS Pro application, and not in its ArcMap application.